# How to find if the row is part of index?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, cardinality

I want find if the row is part of an indexed column in postgresql.

For example:
When I open the table object I see my indexes and the cardinality of the each index.

my total rows in the table is 1,45,454 but the cardinality of the all the indexes are 1,45,300. Some 150 odd rows are not indexed in any of the indexes that I have created.

I ran the below query to find the cardinality,

```
SELECT relname, 
       relkind, 
       reltuples AS cardinality, 
       relpages 
FROM   pg_class 
WHERE  relname LIKE '%table_name%';
```

Could someone please explain why some rows are left as part of indexing and how to find the rows the 150 rows that are not indexed in my original table.

Comment: Rows are not indexed. Columns on the other hand are.

Comment: @Antoniossss Agreed that was my mistake in framing the question. Is there anyway to find the missing rows as part of the index.

Comment: there are no "missing rows". Its just duplicate index entries. If you want that, `GOUP BY` index subjects

Answer (score 2):

> *my total rows in the table is 1,45,454 but the cardinality of the all the indexes are 1,45,300*

that means you have 154 duplicated index entries thus some of those 154 index entries(or less) points to more than 1 row(or more).

Answer (score 1):

From the [postgres documentation on planner statistics](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/planner-stats.html):

> For efficiency reasons, `reltuples` and `relpages` are not updated on-the-fly, and so they usually contain somewhat out-of-date values. They are updated by `VACUUM`, `ANALYZE`, and a few DDL commands such as `CREATE INDEX`. A `VACUUM` or `ANALYZE` operation that does not scan the entire table (which is commonly the case) will incrementally update the `reltuples` count on the basis of the part of the table it did scan, resulting in an approximate value. In any case, the planner will scale the values it finds in `pg_class` to match the current physical table size, thus obtaining a closer approximation.

In other words, as long as that number is approximately correct, there's nothing wrong and nothing to worry about. If it were wildly off (say "203" instead of its current value), then it would be time to issue a `VACUUM` or `ANALYZE` job on the table.

Also worth checking the value of [`default_statistics_target`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-query.html#GUC-DEFAULT-STATISTICS-TARGET). If that's set too low, your statistics will end up less and less accurate.